# CKEditor 5: How to trigger downcast conversion from custom event?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I developed a plugin for CKEditor 5 that allows to display certain predefined non-printing characters (e.g. non-breaking spaces, line breaks) to the user, without changing the underlying model data. This is implemented as an editing downcast conversion, which is triggered by `insert:text$` events. The basic structure of the plugin is as follows:

```js
export class ShowNonprintableCharactersPlugin extends Plugin {

    public init(): void {
        const editor = this.editor;

        editor.conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' ).add( dispatcher => {
            dispatcher.on( 'insert:$text', ( _, data, conversionApi ) => {
                const writer = conversionApi.writer;
                let modelPosition = data.range.start;
                let viewPosition = conversionApi.mapper.toViewPosition( modelPosition );

                // Parse the data here and use `writer` to replace the non-printing
                // characters with other Unicode characters for visualisation.
                }
            },
            { priority: 'high' } );
        } );
    }
}
```

This works fine so far – the characters are properly replaced in the editor view, while the underlying data uses the unmodified characters. It also works in all scenarios: the conversion is done properly whether the editor is just being loaded with initial data, data is typed in directly by the user, or pasted in from the clipboard.

However, here comes the challenge: I'd like to give this plugin a toolbar button which allows the user to dynamically enable and disable whether non-printing characters are displayed like this. I added an internal state to the plugin that determines whether it's active or inactive, and gave it a button in the UI toolbar that allows to toggle the state.

```js
private isActive: boolean = true;

public init(): void {
    const editor = this.editor;

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'showNonprintableCharacters', locale => {
        const view = new ButtonView( locale );
        view.set( {
            label: 'Show non-printable characters',
            icon: imageIcon,
            tooltip: true,
            isOn: this.isActive
        } );

        view.on( 'execute', () => {
            this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            view.isOn = this.isActive;
        } );

        return view;
    } );

    editor.conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' ).add( dispatcher => {
        dispatcher.on( 'insert:$text', ( _, data, conversionApi ) => {
            if ( !this.isActive || !conversionApi.consumable.consume( data.item, 'insert' ) ) {
                return;
            },

            // …

        { priority: 'high' } );
    } );
}
```

Of course, toggling the plugin's status doesn't generate any `insert` events, as the data hasn't changed. What I would like to do, though, is hook the converter into changes of this plugin state in order to trigger the conversion.

I'm pretty sure that the way to go would be through CKEditor's event system; to fire a custom event when the plugin is turned on or off, and hook the conversion into listening to that custom event in addition to only the regular `insert` events. But I keep getting tangled up in what's the correct method to use for firing the event, and how I can configure the converter to actually listen to it.

I'd be grateful for any help in how I could connect these two parts!